# I need the char_start and char_end for a IMarker

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am creating IMarkers, I have the line number but need the char_start and char_end. When the markers are created the file that the marker is connected to might not be open in the editor. How can I get the char_start and char_end offsets without opening the file? Right now the marker highlights the entire line but I want it to ignore the leading white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself. I am sure there is a more efficient manner to do this but this will work for now for my purposes.

```
IPath path = Path.fromOSString(file);
IFile iFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);

ITextFileBufferManager iTextFileBufferManager = FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager();
ITextFileBuffer iTextFileBuffer = null;
IDocument iDoc = null;
try    {
    iTextFileBufferManager.connect(iFile.getFullPath(), LocationKind.IFILE, new NullProgressMonitor());
    iTextFileBuffer = iTextFileBufferManager.getTextFileBuffer(iFile.getFullPath(), LocationKind.IFILE);
    iDoc = iTextFileBuffer.getDocument();

    iTextFileBufferManager.disconnect(iFile.getFullPath(), LocationKind.IFILE, new NullProgressMonitor());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int start = iDoc.getLineOffset(iline - 1);
int end = iDoc.getLineLength(iline - 1);

//this next section was done to remove the leading white spaces                  
while(iDoc.getChar(start) == ' ' || iDoc.getChar(start) == '\t'){                                   
    start++;
    end--;
}

 final int charStart = start;
 final int charEnd = start + end;
```

Comment: Note that you include line delimiter. So if you put cursor at the end of the line and hit 'enter' the marker will be "continued" on next line. If this is not what you want you should substract `iDoc.getLineDelimiter(iLine -1).length()` to charEnd (with appropriate null check). Don't 'just' remove 1 since line ends can be \r\n